# Testing a chrome extension, the behavior of the extension is to check the content of url visted and the show a warning page if matched

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am testing a chrome extension and writing to automate the test case. My use case is to first install the chrome extension and visit the url from my specific data and the show a warning page if the content matched with data our ML team has gathered. i have installed the extension on my chrome browse and then have visited the url. But when i visit the url, the url in the cypress chrome is different from the screen i want to visit. The url shows in the browser is saved as "https://testingurl/__/#/specs/runner?file=cypress/e2e/url.cy.js"   and my actual url is "https://testingurl/c_landingpage/landings/c_185625/landing?click_id=493662245637960268".

My extension behavior is to match the url and then match the title and then content of the page. In the case described case, we have two different urls. How to solve this issue in cypress?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am testing a chrome extension. The behavior of the extension is to check the urls that are opened in the chrome browser. All the url that i am hitting is saved in database. If the url matched then the behavior of the extension is to show a warning page that does not allow the user to view the real content of the website. I want to open that url and verify the content and the url of the website. But in cypress, the url that is being opened has also the file path. In this scenaior my extension is unable to verify the url that is opened in the cypress.